# Renaming netatalk volume with Timemachine

Tags: macos, ubuntu, time-machine, netatalk

I have set up avahi and netatalk on my NAS to provide a Timemachine share for my MacBooks. At the time of setting this up, I had no idea of the intricacies of how this works (neither from the Ubuntu nor the Mac side), so I just blindly followed some guides and did hacky PD from there.

Come to think of it, I still don't quite understand how Apple file systems (including Timemachine) nor netatalk, so hence my question.

I have this `/etc/netatalk/afp.conf` file:

```
[Global]
; Global server settings

[Homes]
basedir regex = /mnt/homes/

[TimeMachine]
path = /mnt/data/TimeMachine
time machine = yes
```

This works well, but I would really like the TimeMachine share to have a more descriptive name, e.g. "TimeMachine on my NAS".

What are the implications of just changing the name in the section heading? Will this work transparently or will all connected Macs suddenly loose their Timemachine history?

Comment: Netatalk seems like the wrong solution. AFP has been deprecated for like a decade now (modern SMB is the preferred remote filesystem protocol of Macs now), and AppleTalk has been deprecated for almost two decades now. You should be able to set up an SMB3 share and advertise it with Bonjour (IETF ZeroConf, mDNS, DNS-SD) and be done.

Comment: For Timemachine access? I think that's a specific protocol that doesn't work on SMB, isn't it?

Comment: Time Machine over the network just makes a sparsebundle disk image on the server, so it doesn't need a filesystem protocol that supports all the right semantics. SMB is fine as far as I know.

Comment: Do you know how to set that up, then? My original question is about how to migrate my existing, working configuration to a differently named share without losing history.